# AGL vs NSOpenGLView in terms of speed

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, macos-carbon

The debate often posed with this comparison is: which framework is better to use as the window for your CGL context. And in suit most would say go with Cocoa instead of Carbon as Carbon is deprecated. However my question lies more in the overhead and speed. It seems evident that Cocoa is not the most performance driven framework as it's main purpose is for utility interfaces. Also I've heard that Objective-C is not the fastest language out there due to abstraction layers. So would it be faster to setup an OpenGL context using the Legacy Carbon `HIView` or to go with Cocoa like suggested and just use an `NSOpenGLView`?

If they turn out to not really have any extra CPU cost could an argument be made that one receives input events faster than the other?

Comment: AGL's fine up until the point where you need something newer than OpenGL 2.1 and it won't give you it. The only way to get a core context is through CGL or NSOpenGL.

Comment: I've been trying to bypass both Carbon and Cocoa with Core Graphics Services + CGL but it's impossible to find the right API calls

Comment: There is no public API that can replace all of Cocoa (it is true that NSOpenGL is layered on top of CGL, but using private / undocumented parts of that API). You wind up with a horrific situation where AGL gets you windowed-mode rendering but NOT a core profile and CGL gets you fullscreen. The only way to do this stuff portably since CGL is deprecated and AGL is already not functional, would be to wrap the NSOpenGL interfaces.

Comment: I don't think we can really talk performance here because one of these codepaths is obsolete already :-\